# How to add models in controller in my own Modules?(Yii2)

Tags: php, yii2

I use Yii2 for create an web application. In this application i need to create my own Module. I create Home module, and put there `Module.php` class, and 3 folders(MVC). After i configure the application(`main.php`) and "add" my module.
In controller i load view and test it in browser. Its works fine without using models. When i want to add model in controller, it show some error. Please help me to customize my controller for use model.
I tried this path in controller for model:
`app\modules\home\model\MyOwnSuperModel`
but it doesnt work, have any ideas?
Thanks.

P.S. Model i create with generator Gii.

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: show the controller code and the error .

Comment: Full description of the error can not write(it was on my work), but the meaning of the error was incorrectly namespace.